# How can I set my target date in countdown timer

Tags: javascript, php, html, timer, countdown

I have this code that I got from
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Countdown</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.countdown.css">
<style type="text/css">
#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 3 - 1, 29);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());


});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I can set my target time which include in this line after the getFullYear():

```
austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 3 - 1, 29);
```

that will came from a variable.

btw, + 1, 3 - 1, 29 is equivalent to 2016 March 29.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to try Carbon: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon